How to get all affiliates total earning
tables :
USER( id, email, affiliate_id, referral_id )
TRANSACTION( id, user_id, amount, txn_fee, status )
note: affiliates get bonus 5% only on the fist deposit(transaction)
i tried this query but its not correct
SELECT email,sum(t.amount),min(t.created) 
FROM user as u 
INNER JOIN transaction as t 
WHERE u.id = t.user_id and t.status=1 
GROUP BY u.id;


so if user has amounts 100, 50, 50 then total should be 205? order by created?

Your question seems too incomplete.

What MySQL version you have?

Not correct for what? You haven't explained what you're trying to do. What does the 5% bonus have to do with this?
